# Instagram navigation after Python Requests not working

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram

I have started building a web scraper for Instagram and am trying to NOT use Selenium (have build prior ones with Selenium, need something faster). I know the Instagram API won't be around for much longer so didn't want to deal with it.

The issue I am encountering is the 'following' website is not being recognized as signed in.  I can successfully sign into the login page and navigate to the user's profile page, but once I attempt a 'GET' request on the following page it signals that I need to login.  Here is the code in python using the requests library:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'accounts/login/ajax/'

def login():
    """Logs in to instagram."""
    session.headers.update(
        {'Referer': BASE_URL, 'user-agent': STORIES_UA})
    req = session.get(BASE_URL)

    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})

    login_data = {'username': USERNAME, 'password': PASSWORD}
    login = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
    session.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
    loginVerification = login.json()

    """
    Check that the user is actually authenticated in the JSON
    """
    if loginVerification['authenticated'] == True and login.status_code == 200:
        print("Successful login")
    else:
        print("Invalid login")
        if login.status_code != 200:
            print("Client error")

    print(login.url)

    """Get to user home page"""
    user_page = session.get(YOURPAGE_URL)
    if user_page.status_code == 200:
        print("Successful navigation to user page")
        print(user_page.url)
    else:
        print("Couldn't get to user page")

    """Next we need to get the user's followers"""
    session.headers.update({'Referer': FOLLOWERS_URL})
    follower_page = session.get(FOLLOWERS_URL)
    if follower_page.status_code == 200:
        print("Successful navigation to followers page")
        print(follower_page.url)
    else:
        print("Couldn't get to followers page")
```

When i print out the URL's of the different pages after making GET requests, they are correct for the user profile page but not once I try and reach the following page.

I should be directed to this: `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/following/`

But am sent to this instead: `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/USERNAME/following/`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Web-scraping, in my opinion, is tawdry; but maybe what you're missing is the api key (and maybe session cookie, etc.) needed for further requests under that session.

Comment: If you are working with Instagram Stuff like this you need session and Cookie to Store your login, then you will not be redirected to log in, I used  some scripts related to Instagram in Kali Linux

Comment: @AdrianM. Besides regarding your thoughts on web-scraping, what would the 'api-key' be for the requests library? The session object in my code should store the cookies for that entire session, I don't believe I need to add them manually.

Comment: @Ramesh I am using the session object which should (from my understanding of the documentation) store the cookies without manually inputting them.  What scripts are you referring to?

Comment: Six months back I Used This Script --- (https://github.com/thelinuxchoice/inshackle)

Comment: @Ramesh Thank you for the bash script, any ideas on how to do it via python though? This is something I was hoping could be done using some python library

Comment: No, As I recently started using Python, I have no idea of doing it in Python